# How to use mysql-connector to retrieve a datetime value?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to retrieve a row off of a table called `players`, which contains a column named `lastheal`, of type `datetime`.
My code is as follows :

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="xxxx", database="xxxx", user="xxxx", passwd="xxxx")
        c = conn.cursor(prepared=True)
        c.execute("""SELECT * FROM players WHERE nameplayer = %s""", (name,))
        for player in c:
            print player
```

I have no trouble retrieving rows from other tables that do not contain `datetime` values. However, the above code produces following error :

```
File "~/player.py", line 14, in __init__
    for player in c:
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 1245, in fetchone
    return self._row_to_python(row, self.description)
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 1231, in _row_to_python
    row = self._connection.converter.row_to_python(rowdata, desc)
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py", line 407, in row_to_python
    result[i] = self._cache_field_types[field_type](row[i], field)
File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py", line 506, in _DATETIME_to_python
    (date_, time_) = value.split(b' ')
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I get `mysql.connector` to retrieve rows with `datetime` values in a correct way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are receiving the `datetime` as an object. Hence why the error says `'datetime.datetime object` has no attribute 'split'. You are trying to run a string-based method on an object.

Try converting your data from the results into a string first using `str()`. Then run your functions on it.

Comment: I edited `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py line 506` from `(date_, time_) = value.split(b' ')` to `(date_, time_) = str(value).split(b' ')` and it seems to be working.

I'm not sure, would it be a bug in `mysql-connector` ?

Comment: After trying to print the result, that's what I get : `{u'lastheal': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 29, 10, 22, 13), u'idplayer': 13, u'idstatus': 1, u'lastencounter': None, u'nameplayer': u'Dude', u'idopponent': None}`. Does this mean I can manipulate `player['lastheal']` as a normal python `datetime` object ?

Comment: On doing some more research, it looks like it could be a bug. I'm not sure how you will be able to manipulate `player['lastheal']` now, but it's worth a try!